# How to pass command line arguments to MonoMac application?

Tags: c#, macos, mono, monodevelop, monomac

I have a C# application with GUI created using Monodevelop 3 and MonoMac libraries. After build, I get a mac app with embedded mono v3 runtime.

Application runs fine, but it does not receive any command line arguments that i pass to it.

```
static void Main (string[] args)
{
 // args are always empty
}
```

I've tried passing them using

```
open -a /Applicaitons/MyApp.app --args my_command_line_arg
```

and even just running generated executable directly

```
/Applicaitons/My.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp my_command_line_arg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the MonoMac application bundle, the actual 'application' is usually a shell script and AFAIK it does not pass it's arguments to the executable.

I don't think this is possible currently; I have heard of people working around this by using environment variables instead.

Comment: I tried exactly what Alex did and it works just fine. I guess if it works in my project this answer is not quite right. I suppose there is a bug fix in the latest version of MonoMac that resolves the issue observed earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with the latest version of Xamarin Studio (4.2.2, build 2) and MonoMac and it works just fine. It seems that MonoMac used to have a bug which is fixed now.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass command line arguments to your MonoMac application if you call it through the shell script. From [Running Mono Applications](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3aRunning_Mono_Applications):

> (...) if you had "myprogram.exe" you could create a shell script
>   called "myprogram" that had the contents:
>
> **#!/bin/sh**
>      **/usr/bin/mono /usr/lib/APPLICATION/myprogram.exe "$@"**
>
> When you run "myprogram," the shell will replace $@ with any arguments
>   you provided.

This works for my MonoMac application built in Xamarin Studio.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but how can it be applied when mono runtime is embedded in application and is not present separately on the computer?